# Using MessagePack with Android

Tags: java, android, msgpack, messagepack

Has someone tried to use `MessagePack` with an  Android app?
Is it possible? I have tried to use the Jar from [`msgpack-java`](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-java) and received the following Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
  at org.msgpack.Packer.pack(Packer.java:532)
  at org.msgpack.MessagePack.pack(MessagePack.java:31)
  ... 15 more
  Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
  at org.msgpack.template.TemplateRegistry.<clinit>(TemplateRegistry.java:38)
  ... 17 more
  Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: org.msgpack.template.BeansFieldEntryReader
  at org.msgpack.template.builder.BeansTemplateBuilder.<init (BeansTemplateBuilder.java:42)
  at org.msgpack.template.builder.BuilderSelectorRegistry.initForJava(BuilderSelectorRegistry.java:73)
  at org.msgpack.template.builder.BuilderSelectorRegistry.<clinit>(BuilderSelectorRegistry.java:38)
  ... 18 more
```

The code that I use is very simple

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
Message msg = new Message();
msg.body = "asdasdasd";
msg.from = "qwe";
msg.to = "ttt";
byte[] bytes = MessagePack.pack(msg);
out.print(bytes);
out.flush();
```

I have `javassist.jar`, `msgpack-0.5.2.jar`, `slf4j-api-1.6.2.jar` and `slf4j-jdk14-1.6.2.jar` in my `lib` directory.

In my server application this code works fine with the same libraries.

Comment: Is this the full stack trace you get? ExceptionInInitializerError is caused by some exception which happens during loading of the class, so there has to be something else as there isn't any class loading happening in your stack trace.

Comment: No, i edited my post, so it's almost full stack (a deleted a part with java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity, it's not so informative)

Comment: Please post the **entire** stack trace

Comment: I hope this may be helpful, :), https://github.com/chzyer/msgpack-for-android

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## (Hopefully) FINAL UPDATE

**msgpack** : `0.6.8` works on Android without any problems

**msgpack-rpc** : [`0.7.0`](http://msgpack.org/maven2/org/msgpack/msgpack-rpc/0.7.0/) works on Android with one caveat.

Specifically, you need to add the following to `onCreate` for API Level 8 (Android 2.2.1), and possibly lower:

```
java.lang.System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true");
java.lang.System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv6Addresses", "false");
```

due to [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9431).

If you want to see a simple example, here's a pair of projects set up for this purpose:

- https://github.com/mikkoz/msgpack-android-test-server/tree/master/msgpack-android-test-server
- https://github.com/mikkoz/msgpack-android-test-client/tree/master/msgpack-android-test-client

---

### Previous Versions

**UPDATE: as of 0.6.7 [msgpack should be compatible with Android](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-java/blob/msgpack-0.6.7/CHANGES.txt) (there is a small dependency exclusion issue). Check the text below for msgpack-rpc (which also might be adapted in the future).**

**NOTE: If you're also using *msgpack-rpc*, you need to do the following steps:**

1. Download the msgpack-rpc source from *git://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-rpc.git* (specifically, the **"java" folder**).
2. Change the main msgpack artifact version to the one you've built.
3. In *org.msgpack.rpc.loop.netty.NettyEventLoop*, change the *NioClientSocketChannelFactory* to *OioClientSocketChannelFactory(getWorkerExecutor())*.
4. Build the MessagePack-RPC in the same way as in the case of the main MessagePack JAR (see *Step 11* above).

The *NettyEventLoop* replacement is due to this issue:
*http://markmail.org/message/ypa3nrr64kzsyfsa* .

**Important:** I've only tested **synchronous** communication. Asynchronous might not work.

---

*And here's the reason for msgpack not working with Android prior to `0.6.7`:*

The reason for the error is that MessagePack uses several java.beans classes that are not included in the Android SDK. You're probably using the *MessagePackBeans* annotation.

This is a similar problem to the one described [here](http://meteatamel.wordpress.com/2010/08/25/android-api-and-java-beans-package/), for which the general solution is outlined [here](http://meteatamel.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/android-api-and-java-beans-package-2/). Unfortunately, in our case it requires a rebuild of msgpack. Here's what I did (you can almost certainly skip Steps 5 and 8, but I haven't tried it that way) :

1. Download the MessagePack source from *https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-java.git*.
2. Import the MessagePack source as a project in your IDE.
3. Download the Apache Harmony source for the relevant packages from *http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/harmony/enhanced/java/trunk/classlib/modules/beans/src/main/java* .
4. Copy these packages into your MessagePack project's *src/main/java* folder:

   - java.beans
   - java.beans.beancontext
   - org.apache.harmony.beans
   - org.apache.harmony.beans.internal.nls
5. In your MessagePack project, remove the following classes:

   - PropertyChangeListener
   - IndexedPropertyChangeEvent
   - PropertyChangeEvent
   - PropertyChangeListenerProxy
   - PropertyChangeSupport
6. Rename the *java.beans* packages to something different, e.g. *custom.beans* .
7. Change **all** *java.beans* references to the renamed ID, so again e.g. *custom.beans*. This applies **especially** to *BeansFieldEntryReader* (this class is the reason for the original error).
8. Change the *custom.beans* references for the five classes you removed in **Step 5** back to *java.beans*.
9. In the *org.apache.harmony.beans.internal.nls.Messages* class, comment out the method *setLocale*, and remove the imports associated with it.
10. Remove all classes that still have errors, **except** *Encoder*. In that class, comment out all references to the classes you've removed. You should now have an error-free project.
11. Build the MessagePack JAR:

    - If you're using Maven, change the version in the pom.xml to something unique, run Maven build with the *install* goal, then add the dependency in your Android project **with that version**.
    - If you're **not** using Maven, you have to run the *jar* goal for Ant with the included *build.xml*. Replace the msgpack JAR in your Android project with this one.
12. If you're publishing your app, remember to include the relevant legal notice for Apache Harmony. It's an Apache License, just like MessagePack.

That should do it. Using your example code, and my own data class, I was successfully able to pack and unpack data.

The entire renaming ritual is due to the fact that the DEX compiler complains about java.* package naming.

Comment: You're welcome - it was a bit of a PITA, but it definitely works :). FYI, I've added a relevant post in MessagePack's user group:
http://groups.google.com/group/msgpack/browse_thread/thread/89a2c47f8031f956
.

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato Do you think the same would be possible to port `javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement` to Android? My question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237082/how-to-query-a-web-service-via-post-request-in-android).

Comment: @mikołak Looks like it still uses non-Android packages. Lint says: `Invalid package reference in library; not included in Android: java.applet. Referenced from javassist.tools.rmi.ObjectImporter.` and `Invalid package reference in library; not included in Android: javax.tools. Referenced from org.msgpack.util.TemplatePrecompiler.`

Answer (score 0):

There is a critical msgpack bug saying data packed with msgpack will get corrupted on the Dalvik VM. http://jira.msgpack.org/browse/MSGPACK-51

Comment: I'm reasonably certain you can work around it by using @MessagePackBeans instead. That's what I used in testing.

Answer (score 0):

There is an ongoing effort by @TheTerribleSwiftTomato and the MessagePack core team to get MessagePack working on Android, please see the related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-java/issues/15). The fix mentioned in @TheTerribleSwiftTomato's answer is to be found [here](https://github.com/mikkoz/msgpack-java).

**Update**

I've managed to get it at least running on Android by (painstakingly) adding all the necessary `javassist` Classes which are currently required for the build to succeed. An extra `600KB` gain in size, yet at least it seems to work. All in all, it appears to be working to some extent on Android, eventually check out the lesser-known resources about Message Pack such as its [User Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/msgpack) and its [Wiki](http://wiki.msgpack.org/display/MSGPACK/Home) for more information.

On a side-note, be sure to use a HTTP Request Library (such as LoopJ's [Android Async HTTP](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) or Apache's [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)) which can **handle binary data**.

Last but not least you can ping me if there is interest in this `jar` which makes MessagePack seemingly work on Android – credits go out of course to @TheTerribleSwiftTomato who supplied the fix above!

Comment: Still have the same problem, any help ?

Comment: Google me and write an e-mail, I'll get back to you this evening and mail you the .jar which worked for me. Although the issue seems to be resolved in MessagePack, see https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-java/issues/15

Comment: it gives me java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.msgpack.MessagePack

Comment: Ok, did you perhaps forget to add the MessagePack .jar within your Classpath? (In Eclipse, use Project Properties » Libraries and Code » External Libraries » Add External JAR [from the top of my head])

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you write this in the main proguard-rules file-

```
-dontwarn org.msgpack.**
-keep class org.msgpack.** { *; }
```