# Proguard giving "Warning: org.msgpack.*"

Tags: android, proguard

Using Eclipse to export my project, I get the following warnings:

```
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Note: there were 3023 duplicate class definitions.
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.BeansBuildContext: can't find referenced class javassist.CtClass
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.BeansBuildContext: can't find referenced class javassist.CtClass
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.BeansBuildContext: can't find referenced class javassist.CtNewConstructor
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.BeansBuildContext: can't find referenced class javassist.CtClass
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.BeansBuildContext: can't find referenced class javassist.CannotCompileException
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.BeansBuildContext: can't find referenced class javassist.NotFoundException
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.BeansBuildContext: can't find referenced class javassist.CtNewConstructor
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.BeansBuildContext: can't find referenced class javassist.CtConstructor
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.BuildContext: can't find referenced class javassist.CtClass
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.BuildContext: can't find referenced class javassist.CtClass
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.BuildContext: can't find referenced class javassist.CtClass
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.BuildContext: can't find referenced class javassist.CtClass
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.BuildContext: can't find referenced class javassist.CtClass
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.BuildContext: can't find referenced class javassist.CtNewMethod
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.BuildContext: can't find referenced class javassist.CtClass
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.BuildContext: can't find referenced class javassist.CtClass
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.BuildContext: can't find referenced class javassist.CtClass
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.BuildContext: can't find referenced class javassist.CannotCompileException
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.BuildContext: can't find referenced class javassist.NotFoundException
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.BuildContext: can't find referenced class javassist.CtNewMethod
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.BuildContext: can't find referenced class javassist.CtClass
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.BuildContext: can't find referenced class javassist.CtClass
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.BuildContext: can't find referenced class javassist.CtClass
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.BuildContext: can't find referenced class javassist.CtClass
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.BuildContext: can't find referenced class javassist.CtMethod
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.BuildContext: can't find referenced class javassist.CtClass
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.BuildContext: can't find referenced class javassist.CtClass
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.BuildContext: can't find referenced class javassist.CtClass
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.BuildContext: can't find referenced class javassist.CtMethod
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.DefaultBuildContext: can't find referenced class javassist.CtClass
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.DefaultBuildContext: can't find referenced class javassist.CtClass
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.DefaultBuildContext: can't find referenced class javassist.CtNewConstructor
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.DefaultBuildContext: can't find referenced class javassist.CtClass
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.DefaultBuildContext: can't find referenced class javassist.CannotCompileException
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.DefaultBuildContext: can't find referenced class javassist.NotFoundException
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.DefaultBuildContext: can't find referenced class javassist.CtNewConstructor
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.DefaultBuildContext: can't find referenced class javassist.CtConstructor
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.JavassistTemplateBuilder: can't find referenced class javassist.ClassPool
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.JavassistTemplateBuilder: can't find referenced class javassist.ClassPool
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.JavassistTemplateBuilder: can't find referenced class javassist.ClassPool
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.JavassistTemplateBuilder: can't find referenced class javassist.LoaderClassPath
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.JavassistTemplateBuilder: can't find referenced class javassist.LoaderClassPath
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.JavassistTemplateBuilder: can't find referenced class javassist.ClassPool
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.JavassistTemplateBuilder: can't find referenced class javassist.ClassPool
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.JavassistTemplateBuilder: can't find referenced class javassist.ClassPool
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.JavassistTemplateBuilder: can't find referenced class javassist.ClassPool
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.JavassistTemplateBuilder: can't find referenced class javassist.NotFoundException
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.JavassistTemplateBuilder: can't find referenced class javassist.ClassPool
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.JavassistTemplateBuilder: can't find referenced class javassist.CtClass
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.JavassistTemplateBuilder: can't find referenced class javassist.CtClass
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.util.TemplatePrecompiler: can't find referenced class javax.tools.ToolProvider
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.util.TemplatePrecompiler: can't find referenced class javax.tools.DiagnosticCollector
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.util.TemplatePrecompiler: can't find referenced class javax.tools.DiagnosticCollector
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.util.TemplatePrecompiler: can't find referenced class javax.tools.JavaCompiler
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.util.TemplatePrecompiler: can't find referenced class javax.tools.StandardLocation
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.util.TemplatePrecompiler: can't find referenced class javax.tools.JavaFileManager
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.util.TemplatePrecompiler: can't find referenced class javax.tools.JavaFileObject
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.util.TemplatePrecompiler: can't find referenced class javax.tools.JavaFileObject
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.util.TemplatePrecompiler: can't find referenced class javax.tools.JavaFileObject$Kind
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.util.TemplatePrecompiler: can't find referenced class javax.tools.JavaCompiler
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.util.TemplatePrecompiler: can't find referenced class javax.tools.JavaFileManager
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.util.TemplatePrecompiler: can't find referenced class javax.tools.ToolProvider
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.util.TemplatePrecompiler: can't find referenced class javax.tools.JavaCompiler
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.util.TemplatePrecompiler: can't find referenced class javax.tools.StandardLocation
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.util.TemplatePrecompiler: can't find referenced class javax.tools.JavaFileManager
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.util.TemplatePrecompiler: can't find referenced class javax.tools.JavaFileManager$Location
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.util.TemplatePrecompiler: can't find referenced class javax.tools.JavaFileObject
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.util.TemplatePrecompiler: can't find referenced class javax.tools.JavaCompiler
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.util.TemplatePrecompiler: can't find referenced class javax.tools.JavaFileManager
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.util.TemplatePrecompiler: can't find referenced class javax.tools.JavaFileObject$Kind
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.util.TemplatePrecompiler$1: can't find referenced class javax.tools.JavaFileObject$Kind
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.util.TemplatePrecompiler$1: can't find referenced class javax.tools.JavaFileObject$Kind
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.util.TemplatePrecompiler$1: can't find referenced class javax.tools.JavaFileObject
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.util.TemplatePrecompiler$1: can't find referenced class javax.tools.JavaFileObject$Kind
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.util.json.JSONUnpacker: can't find referenced class org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.util.json.JSONUnpacker: can't find referenced class org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.util.json.JSONUnpacker: can't find referenced class org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.util.json.JSONUnpacker: can't find referenced class org.json.simple.parser.ParseException
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.util.json.JSONUnpacker: can't find referenced class org.json.simple.parser.ParseException
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.util.json.JSONUnpacker: can't find referenced class org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: org.msgpack.util.json.JSONUnpacker: can't find referenced class org.json.simple.parser.ParseException
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] Warning: there were 81 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj]  at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj]  at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj]  at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2013-08-20 10:45:24 - MyProj]  at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

project.properties:

```
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-myproject.txt

# Project target.
target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:17
android.library.reference.1=../../../android/downloaded/JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-e5c2d1c/library
android.library.reference.2=../../../android/android-sdk-macosx/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib
```

proguard-myproject.txt:

```
# To enable ProGuard in your project, edit project.properties
# to define the proguard.config property as described in that file.
#
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the ProGuard
# include property in project.properties.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:
-injars      bin/classes
-injars      libs
-outjars     bin/classes-processed.jar
-libraryjars /Users/tester/Documents/workspace/android_testing/MyProj/libs/MixpanelAPI.jar
-libraryjars /Users/tester/Documents/workspace/android_testing/MyProj/libs/Parse-1.3.2.jar      
-libraryjars /Users/tester/Documents/workspace/android_testing/MyProj/libs/TestFlightLib.jar
-libraryjars /Users/tester/Documents/workspace/android_testing/MyProj/libs/android-support-v13.jar
-libraryjars /Users/tester/Documents/android/android-sdk-macosx/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/libs/google-play-services.jar

-dontpreverify
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
   public void *(android.view.View);
   public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}

-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep class com.parse.** { *; }
-keep class com.mixpanel.** { *; }
-keep class com.testflightapp.** { *; }
-keep class org.json.simple.** { *; }

-dontwarn com.facebook.**
-dontwarn android.support.**

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
```

Some third party things I am using are mixpanel.com, parse.com, ActionBarSherlock (http://actionbarsherlock.com/), and [TestFlightApp.com](https://testflightapp.com/).

I did try to put in the following into my proguard-myproject.txt:

```
-dontwarn javassist.**
-dontwarn javax.tools.**
-dontwarn json.simple.parser.**
```

However, if I put those in my app crashes immediately after I launch the app, so I am guessing I need to clean up the warnings by including libraries properly.

#### Question:

I was wondering what I needed to include in my proguard-myproject.txt file to get rid of these warnings and be able to launch my app on my phone without it crashing immediately after I launch the app. If I run the app from eclipse in just the normal Run.. or Debug option, the app works fine so I am guessing somehow Proguard is removing some classes I need.

I do also have the dump.txt, mapping.txt, seeds.txt, and usage.txt if anyone needs to see them, but they are fairly long so I thought no need to paste here for now.

### Solved!

thanks to @Eric Lafortune and looking [proguard documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html#enabling)

Main problem was just adding this:

```
-keep class com.myapp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.myapp.** { *; }
```

where com.myapp.** is the package for my app

proguard-myproject.txt:

```
-injars      bin/classes
-injars      libs
-outjars     bin/classes-processed.jar
-libraryjars libs/MixpanelAPI.jar
-libraryjars libs/Parse-1.3.2.jar       
-libraryjars libs/TestFlightLib.jar
-libraryjars libs/android-support-v13.jar
-libraryjars libs/KiipSDK.jar
-libraryjars /Users/tester/Documents/android/android-sdk-macosx/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/libs/google-play-services.jar

-dontpreverify
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider

-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
   public void *(android.view.View);
   public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}

-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.** { *; }
#-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
#-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep class com.parse.** { *; }
-keep class com.mixpanel.** { *; }
-keep class com.testflightapp.** { *; }
-keep class org.json.simple.** { *; }
-keep class com.myapp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.myapp.** { *; }

-dontwarn com.facebook.**
-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn org.msgpack.**
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using MessagePack with Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529522/using-messagepack-with-android)

Comment: To elaborate: the problem you described is covered by the answers to the linked question.

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato, was not sure how to reply to you other than comment. Anyway, thanks for the info! Hopefully I'll get some time to look into this further

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Ant/Eclipse/Gradle build processes in the Android SDK automatically specify input jars, library jars, and output jars for you, so you mustn't specify them again in the configuration. This is why you are getting lots of warnings about duplicate classes.

On the other hand, some org.msgpack classes depend on classes that are not in your libs directory. If your debug build works fine, you can tell ProGuard to ignore it with:

```
-dontwarn org.msgpack.**
```

If your application crashes, you should look at the logcat output. You can find suggestions in the [Troubleshooting](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html) section of the ProGuard manual.

Comment: thanks! looks like this in addition to what I edited above fixed it!

Comment: and run sdk as administrator+ run eclipse as administrator
and add to your manifest file: 
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>