# Javassist Runtime Error with msgpack-java

Tags: java, msgpack

I am trying to use messagepack to send data back and forth between an Arduino and a Java application, and I am having trouble setting up the java implementation of messagepack: msgpack-java (https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-java/wiki/QuickStart).

I wanted to avoid building the entire library myself, so I used v0.6.8 from [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/msgpack/msgpack/0.6.8/).

The sample code compiles successfully but at runtime I get

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/ClassPath
```

specifically at the line

```
MessagePack msgpack = new MessagePack();
```

I tried just building the msgpack jar myself, but I got compile errors on the source code because it is missing javassist packages. I do not know where to get the correct packages, and unfortunately the developers don't mention that in the documentation. I couldn't find a comments section on their page so I was hoping that someone on here could help me get msgpack working.

I also looked at this question ([Using MessagePack with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529522/using-messagepack-with-android/11965096#11965096)) but it was not really clear about where I can get the libraries I need.

Answer (score 3):

I guess this was a fairly obvious question but I'll answer it here in case anybody else is having troubles like me. I ended up learning about the dependencies I needed by looking at the Maven POM file. This file told me that I needed the [json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) library and the [javassist](https://github.com/jboss-javassist/javassist) library. I just downloaded the .jar files for these two libraries and added them to the eclipse build path and everything ran just fine.

As an alternative, consider sirbrialliance's stripped-down static implementation: https://bitbucket.org/sirbrialliance/msgpack-java-lite
This is a bit better documented and easier to set-up initially.